# Text of Asp:button not visible

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-core, button

I am using asp.net core.

I have the following code:

```
<asp:Button ID="updateNotesBtn" Text="&#10004;" runat="server" OnClick="Click"/>
```

When I run the web app I can see that the button is visible within the HTML, however the text refuses to display. Hovering over the item reveals that a height is missing:

[image: asp:button#updateNotesBtn 0 x 19]

However when I add a height, I still can't see the text, which should display as: ✔. That symbol is displayed elsewhere so that can't be the problem.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

`asp:Button` is an [ASP.NET WebForms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button?view=netframework-4.8) control. If you put this markup on a Razor page, it will simply render as an `asp:Button` element on your page without any WebForms functionality.

Options:

- rewrite your code to [Razor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).
- switch back from ASP.NET Core to [ASP.NET WebForms](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/web-forms).